# How to use htmlparser2 to convert content in html

Tags: html, html-parsing

I need to reverse the "textContent" and "title" text in html in the nodejs environment, what should I do

This is my current code, `htmlparser2": "^6.0.0`

```
import * as htmlparser2 from "htmlparser2";

let data = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body title="hello" class="d-flex">
    body
    <h1>abc</h1>
    <p>def</p>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const reverse = (str: string) => str.split("").reverse().join("");

var handler = new htmlparser2.DomHandler(function (error, tree) {
  //...
});

var parser = new htmlparser2.Parser(handler);
parser.parseComplete(data);
```

I hope to get this result after conversion

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body title="olleh" class="d-flex">
    ydob
    <h1>cba</h1>
    <p>fed</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks ❤️

Comment: I'm actually not sure what your issue is, I pasted exactly what you have into a [StackBlitz application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vgghvy?file=index.ts) and it gives me your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time building this library to solve the problem. [html-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-static)

```
import { AstAttrbute, AstText, htmlAst, traverse } from "html-static";

let data = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body title="hello">
    body
    <h1 id="app">abc</h1>
    <p class='foo'>def</p>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const ast = htmlAst(data);

const reverse = (str) => str.split("").reverse().join("");

traverse(ast, {
  text(text: AstText) {
    text.value = reverse(text.value);
  },
  attr_title(attr: AstAttrbute) {
    attr.value = reverse(attr.value);
  },
}).then((_) => {
  console.log(ast.toString());
});
```

In the end I got this result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body title="olleh">ydob<h1 id="app">cba</h1><p class="foo">fed</p></body></html>
```